# travis no me genera la cobertura de un proyecto node

Tags: npm, chai, nyc, travis-ci, mochajs

Estoy practicando estructuras de datos en typescript y en mi local obtengo el reporte de cobertura sin problemas

[image: reporte de cobertura]

pero en travis-ci no me aparece.

[image: reporte vacio de cobertura en travis]

¿Existirá algún problema de configuación con node o un poblema propio de travis?.

Es mi tercer poyecto con typescript, así que no sé distinguir la diferencia.

Información adicional:

- [Código del proyecto](https://github.com/javatlacati/datastructurestypescript)
- [Traza completa de travis](https://travis-ci.org/javatlacati/datastructurestypescript)
- package.json

```js
{
  "name": "datastructurestypescript",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "nyc mocha -r ts-node/register public/tests/**/*.ts",
    "test": "nyc report --reporter=json",
    "posttest": "codecov -f coverage/*.json -t b8b6c1c6-4dda-4fd4-8298-443e08034f2c"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/javatlacati/datastructurestypescript.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/npm": "^2.0.29",
    "nyc": "^11.4.1",
    "codecov": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "main": "dist/index",
  "typings": "dist/index",
  "author": "RUSLAN LOPEZ",
  "license": "LGPL-3.0-or-later"
}
```

- travis-yml

```
dist: trusty
sudo: false
language: node_js

node_js:
  - node
#  - lts/* # safety net; don't remove
#  - node # safety net; don't remove
before_script:
  - npm install typescript
  - npm install @types/chai
  - npm install @types/mocha
```